# iTunes Connect: how to follow (properly) reviews with an RSS reader/agregator?

Tags: rss, app-store, app-store-connect, rating, review

In Itunes Connect, there is for each app a RSS url (like https://itunes.apple.com/cn/rss/customerreviews/id=XXXXXXXXX/sortBy=mostRecent/xml?l=fr) to follow the user reviews. I copy/pasted this URL in my different readers like Google Reader or Feedly but the problem is that these readers display the title and the comments of the users but not the rating (stars) !  This is really annoying....

I would like to copy/paste the RSS url of all my apps in a reader which ALSO displays the rating (otherwise this RSS stuff is useless). Anybody managed to do this ?

The best would be that this reader also translates the user comments to my language.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the stars don't appear in standard RSS tags, they are there in the "im:rating" tag.

Comment: Thanks. Apple really did a bad job on this point. RSS feeds without stars are useless. I hope they will fix this !